# Keras Neural Network. Preprocessing

Tags: python, scikit-learn, neural-network, keras

I have this doubt when I fit a neural network in a regression problem. I preprocessed the predictors (features) of my train and test data using the methods of **Imputers** and **Scale** from *sklearn.preprocessing*,but I did not preprocessed the class or target of my train data or test data.

In the architecture of my neural network all the layers has **relu** as activation function except the last layer that has the **sigmoid** function. I have choosen the sigmoid function for the last layer because the values of the predictions are between 0 and 1.

**tl;dr:** In summary, my question is: should I deprocess the output of my neuralnet? If I don't use the sigmoid function, the values of my output are < 0 and > 1. In this case, how should I do it?

Thanks

Comment: can you share the network initialisation code as well, basically the `kernel_initializer` and `loss` also matter.

Comment: @Aceconhielo, the last layer must have activation function like sigmoid or softmax in order to predict probabilities. Sigmoid function has values between 0 and 1

Comment: That is the scope of output layer...to predict probabilities to given classes.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, if you are doing regression you should use a linear' activation in the last layer. A sigmoid function will 'favor' values closer to 0 and 1, so it would be harder for your model to output intermediate values.

If the distribution of your targets is gaussian or uniform I would go with a linear output layer. De-processing shouldn't be necessary unless you have very large targets.